# Solution for error: Could not find com.login.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

My problem is basically the following app running on an iOS emulator throws an error in android emulator named `'com.login.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1'` and I can't find a solution.

The situation that gives me the most trouble here is that it asks for `'login service'`, not `'google service'`. I can't solve it in any way.

If you look at this image, you can fully understand the problem.

**Screenshot of the error:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your

> Andriod folder-->App-->build.gradle

then
add this

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${kotlin_version}"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')//this one add this-----------
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
}
```

Comment: note yours request for 28.4.1

Comment: This has already been added, the problem is that it's asking for the login service, not the google service. :(

Comment: okay can u update the gradle in the question let me

Comment: Okay question update.

Comment: you did not update.. i cant see it here

Comment: I've updated the entire question at the top and there's a picture below the question, can you take a look there?

Comment: i am sorry, i cant help like this.... u are not updating what i request for.

Comment: What exactly do you want me to update?